# How to convert CMake project to gn (BUILD.gn)?

Tags: cmake, chromium, gn

I working with custom fork of Chromium, and need introduce some //third_party dependency , which is CMake based project.  Because Chromium uses gn and BUILD.gn as basic "make file" I can't understand how I can build CMake project  with context of Chromium build or how to obtain semantically same BUILD.gn .

Because CMakeLists.txt of CMake project is huge, it's a little bit tricky to convert it manually .

Will be grateful for help.